# Connect to another database if one is not available

Tags: sql-server-2012, laravel-5.4

I would like my site to connect to another database with the same credentials as the current one if the current one is unavailable or not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a connection by using a query and if it fails change the connection.

```
try {
    User::find(1); // or any other SQL query you want to check
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   config(['database.connections.data' => array( // you don't have to add the connection runtime but it can be done.
       'driver'    => 'sqlsrv',
       'host' => $connection['Database_Server'],
       'database' => $connection['Database_Name'],
       'username' => $connection['Database_User'],
       'password' => $connection['Database_Pass'
    )]);

 DB::setDefaultConnection('data'); // change the default connection
```

Comment: This was helpful but is there a way to do this through the .env file or the database config file?

Comment: Yes sure, just add the entries and use that name

Comment: Could you please show me how? I mean it would clearer if you could give an example. @Thomas Moors

Comment: I really don't know how this is to hard for you, but OK.

Comment: Well! I am a newbie